# Is there a climber chest piece?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Climbing is awesome, and climbing fast is better! I bought the Climber's Bandanna and Climber Boots, but can't find the third part of this set. Where can I find/buy it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**. [Climbing Gear](https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Climbing_Gear), the chestpiece of the Climbing Set can be found in [Chaas Qeta Shrine](https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Chaas_Qeta_Shrine) in the Necluda sea. Chaas Qeta Shrine is a Major Test of Strength, and the Climbing Gear is found in the chest at the end of the shrine.

Comment: The whole set has an effect increasing your climb speed. Highly recommend.

Comment: Dang, and I was saving that because I thought I didn't need any more powerful weapons…

Comment: @l0b0 If I recall correctly, those test of strength shrines also reset on a blood moon, so there's no need to save them for the weapons.